# Why do I get the error: Column part of using cannot have a qualifier

Tags: sql, oracle, join, using, ambiguous

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
select
   ordervariety,
   bat.batch,
   order_date,
   var.variety,
   var.the_name,
   bat.the_name,
   var.the_price,
   bat.the_price
   quantity
from
   test_orders
   join TEST_ORDERVARIETIES using (orderno)
   full outer join assessment_varieties var using (variety)
   full outer join test_batches bat using (batch)
where
   ordervariety is not null
```

The tables are structured as follows:
TEST_ORDERS:

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
ORDERNO NUMBER(6,0) No  -   1
SHOP    NUMBER(3,0) No  -   -
ORDER_DATE  DATE    No  -   -
```

TEST_ORDERVARIETIES:

```
ORDERVARIETY    NUMBER(6,0) No  -   1
ORDERNO NUMBER(6,0) No  -   -
VARIETY NUMBER(6,0) Yes -   -
BATCH   NUMBER(6,0) Yes -   -
QUANTITY    NUMBER(3,0) No  -   -
```

TEST_BATCHES:

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
BATCH   NUMBER(6,0) No  -   1
GREENHOUSE  NUMBER(3,0) No  -   -
THE_NAME    VARCHAR2(50)    No  -   -
VARIETY NUMBER(3,0) No  -   -
THE_PRICE   NUMBER(5,2) Yes -   -
```

ASSESSMENT_VARIETIES:

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
VARIETY NUMBER(6,0) No  -   1
SPECIES NUMBER(6,0) No  -   -
THE_NAME    CHAR(64)    Yes -   -
THE_PRICE   NUMBER(8,2) Yes -   -
THE_GROWING_NOTES   CHAR(255)   Yes -   -
```

Why do I get the error: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier?

And what can I do to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456684/mixing-using-and-on-in-oracle-ansi-join

Comment: Something isn't right here.  You're joining to `assessment_varieties` on `variety` but according to the definitions you've posted, none of the tables you had joined up to that point have a `variety` column other than `assessment_varieties`.  What do you expect that join to be doing?

Comment: Sorry my fault, added the wrong table definition for assessment_varieties, check out the updated version

Answer (score 3):

Change your `select` to:

```
select
   ordervariety,
   bat.batch,
   order_date,
   variety,
---^
   var.the_name,
   bat.the_name,
   var.the_price,
   bat.the_price
   quantity
```

When using `USING`, you cannot include a table alias on the columns used in the clause.

EDIT:

The problem is that `variety` is in *three* tables, but only in the `using` clause for a join between two of them.  I'd suggest just being explicit about the joins:

```
select ov.ordervariety, bat.batch, o.order_date,
       var.variety, var.the_name,
       bat.the_name, var.the_price, bat.the_price
       ov.quantity
from test_orders o join
     TEST_ORDERVARIETIES ov
     on o.orderno = ov.oderno full outer join 
     assessment_varieties var
     on var.variety = ov.variety join
     test_batches bat
     on b.batch = ov.batch
where ov.ordervariety is not null;
```

Comment: If I do that then I get the error: "Column ambiguously defined" because variety is in both assessment_varieties and test_batch

Comment: @benjs.1 . . . That would be problem.  Can you include it in the `join`?  Otherwise, just use explicit `on` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Erase the bat from batch and the var from variety in the `SELECT` statement.

You cannot use the alias on these words in the `SELECT` area because you are already qualifying them in the `JOIN` area.

```
 SELECT batch, variety, bat.the_price
```